# Why is InDesign exporting my pdf with compression artefacts only visible on the background?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, background, compression

I'm in the process of literally giving my old CV a new coat of paint. My old, working export settings for getting a clean pdf have been lost with the last re-installing of Windows.
It should not be as complicated as it seems, though and it looks like I am overlooking something basic.
The background is a linked and placed .psd file and does look sharp and clean in InDesign when working, as do the dark shapes that make up the middle layer. However, even when exporting with no compression on the images, the background ends up with visible compression artefacts.
What option have I been overlooking?

[image: Screenshot of the exported pdf, font and dark panels are crisp while background has visible compression artifacts]

Comment: Just looks like JPG compression to me.

Comment: Check your PDF export settings. Are images set to export as JPG? Try a lossless image format instead, or if you need JPG to keep the file size smaller, don't add quite so much compression.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you doing any subsampling when exporting.

Also, check the resolution of the PSD file, perhaps it is much higher than the export resolution.